# Как в тег img установить данные из canvas?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

Есть код, изменяющий фотографии, выбранные пользователем, с помощью холста(canvas). Как его данные поместить в image?

Answer (score 3):

Можно с помощью `canvas.toDataURL();`:

```js
const canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
const w = canvas.width = 200;
const h = canvas.height = 200;

ctx.fillStyle = 'yellow';
ctx.fillRect(0,0,w,h);
ctx.fillStyle = 'red';
ctx.fillRect(50,50,100,100);

const image = new Image();
image.src = canvas.toDataURL();
document.body.append(image);
```